# How to add dynamique values to list of list

Tags: java, list

I have a `List<List<Tableof>>`:

```
List<List<Tableof>> test;
```

I create lists, like `t1` shown below that is added to `test`. How can I create a list like `t1` dynamically because the numbers of those lists aren't fixed.

```
    private List<List<Tableof>> test = new ArrayList<List<Tableof>>();
    List<Tableof> t1 = new ArrayList<Tableof>();
    Query query4 = em.createNamedQuery("Tableof.findAll");
    t1 =  query4.getResultList();
    test.add(t1);
```

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: What? Please elaborate

Comment: i edited my post to be clear.

Comment: How list of lists are different from list of anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getResultList method of the Query class has to return a List<Tableof>.

Here's code that should work.

```
private List<List<Tableof>> test = new ArrayList<List<Tableof>>();

Query query4 = em.createNamedQuery("Tableof.findAll");
List<Tableof> t1 =  query4.getResultList();
test.add(t1);
```

This method would be in the Query class.

```
public List<Tableof> getResultList() {
    List<Tableof> list = new ArrayList<Tableof>()
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (!rs.islast()) {
        rs.next();
        Tableof tableof = (Tableof) rs.getObject();
        list.add(tableof)
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: nice solution .. but if you can show me how i can use this fonction with the query just a simple example .